# AS3:Instancing instances of classes

Tags: actionscript-3, instance, extending-classes

This is my problem: I have a Shared class which extends Main class. In my Shared class i am instancing other classes and adding them to this. class

```
package 
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
public class Shared extends Main
{
    public var m:Mirror = new Mirror(span, i*span+j, _x, _y, size, d);
    public var g:Grid = new Grid(i*span+j,size, addl, span, _x, _y);
    public var b:Ball = new Ball(30); 
    public var mc:MovieClips = new MovieClips(30, _x, _y, size, span); 
    public var l:Level = new Level(levelCount); 
    public function Shared(){
        this.addChild(m); 
        this.addChild(g);
        this.addChild(b);
        this.addChild(mc);
        this.addChild(l);
    }
}

}
```

Now, in my main i also use an instance of Shared like so:

```
private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        var sh:Shared = new Shared();

        stage.addChild(sh.b);
        stage.addChild(sh.mc);
        stage.addChild(sh.l);

        for (i = 0; i < span; i++) 
        {
           for (j = 0; j < span; j++) 
           {
               stage.addChild(sh.g);
               if(addl.indexOf(i*span+j)==true){
                    stage.addChild(sh.m);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't get any errors, but none of the objects appear on stage, i can't find the problem. I think my problem is Shared class is not extending Sprite, but then i would have to pass a huge amount of arguments to Shared, is there any way to bypass this? So i can still extend Main...

Comment: Before you ask new questions you should accept the answers to your previous ones: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260618/actionscript3-moving-objects-of-type-movieclip), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000019/assigning-unique-identifiers-to-array-of-objects-in-actionscript3), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326312/as3-importing-classes-sharing-variables-between-classes)

Comment: I think you need to look into variable scope. Where do all these vars come from: span, i, j, _x, _y, size, d, addl?

Comment: I don't think you want your Shared class to inherit from your main class, it looks like you'll have a stack overflow of `Shared` objects if the init function gets called from the constructor.

Comment: 1) Loose extending the Main (extend Sprite). 2) According you your code you're forgetting to invoke init() call on the Shared instance, but then you'll most likely land on a stack overflow as suggested above.

Comment: how cool is it to actually get to point out a stack overflow on stack overflow...  :) +1 to @LondonDrugs_MediaServices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to have your `Shared` class inherit from your `Main` class, remember that by using the `extends Main` after your class, you inherit all the code from it, which means you're inheriting the function that creates an instance of your `Shared` class, which may cause a stack overflow.

Extending a class is not the same as getting an instance of your class. All the i/j/size etc properties of the main class are a completely separate instance than the ones that will be in your Shared class that inherits Main.

Here is probably what you want to do:

```
public class Shared extends Sprite { //extend Sprite instead of Main
    public var m:Mirror; //don't instantiate these objects yet, just declare them
    public var g:Grid;
    public var b:Ball; 
    public var mc:MovieClips; 
    public var l:Level; 

    public function Shared(main:Main){  //pass in a reference to your main class instance
        //instanciate these objects in your constructor
        m = new Mirror(main.span, main.i*main.span+main.j, main._x, main._y, main.size, main.d); //all these vars (span, i,j,_x,_y, size, d, addl) are not defined anywhere that you've shown, I'm assuming they are part of your main class
        g = new Grid(main.i*main.span+main.j,main.size, main.addl, main.span, main._x, main._y);
        b = new Ball(30); 
        mc = new MovieClips(30, main._x, main._y, main.size, main.span); 
        l = new Level(main.levelCount); 

        this.addChild(m); 
        this.addChild(g);
        this.addChild(b);
        this.addChild(mc);
        this.addChild(l);
    }
}
```

In your main class:

```
private function init(e:Event = null):void 
{
    var sh:Shared = new Shared(this); //pass a reference to this Main class instance

    //stage.addChild(sh.b); // just add the Shared instance to the stage directly
    //stage.addChild(sh.mc);
    //stage.addChild(sh.l);

    addChild(sh); //you only need to add the Shared class instance, since you've already added those other objects in the Shared class

    /* no idea what your trying to do here, but I don't think it's what you're expecting
    for (i = 0; i < span; i++) 
    {
       for (j = 0; j < span; j++) 
       {
           stage.addChild(sh.g);
           if(addl.indexOf(i*span+j)==true){
                stage.addChild(sh.m);
            }
        }
    }
    */
}
```

Please explain your code a bit more and I can update this answer to be more relevant.

Comment: The thing is i don't want all of the objects in shared to be added on stage. Above 3 i want to add only once, sh.g is a grid which consists of small squares so i want that for each iteration and sh.m is added only if index is found in an array.